# Make text appear through the camera

Tags: java, android, camera

i'm getting some doubts about how to make a text appears through the camera when i use it. I mean, when you use a camera, the text appears throught the camera but not in reality.

My first think was to try get some object that represents the camera and try to draw text or some image that represents text, but i don't have any idea of how to make it.

I'm sorry for my english if is bad. If someone don't understand what i'm saying just told me.

Thank you for read my question,
Atap.

Comment: what's the final effect you want ?

Comment: Do you want to perform "Optical Character Recognition" from the image which is taken or seen through your mobile camera?

Comment: Ok i came not specific sorry xD. What i want exactly is that when an user use my "custom camera" in a specific geolocated point he can watch a text that i send throught the camera. The text doesn't exists in reality, only in some poart of my code or in some file.

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay the preview surface with another view with transparent background. On this view you can render your text, simplest way - use fullscreen TextView and tune padding for the text to appear where you want.

The caveat of this naive method is that the preview and overlay cannot be synchronised precisely. The solution is to send camera frames to OpenGL, and render the text in the same OpenGL.